# Inserting into a view with an auto increment primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, sql-insert, sql-view

I have a table `horse` and a view `view_horse` that selects every column from the `horse` table except the primary key (primary key is auto-increment integer) and then presents it to the user, I want to insert data into that views underlying table and naturally expect the primary key to be automatically generated. But I keep getting an SQL exception stating "field of view `view_horse` underlying doesn't have a default value" when I try to insert any data into it.

EDIT -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TRC`.`horse` (
`horse_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`registered_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`stable_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`horse_birth_year` DATE NOT NULL,
`horse_height` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
`horse_location` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TRC',
`arrival_date` DATE NOT NULL,
`passport_no` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
`is_deceased` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`arrival_weight` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
`horse_sex` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
`microchip_no` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
`date_of_death` DATE NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`horse_id`),
INDEX `fk_Horses_SexLookup1_idx` (`horse_sex` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Horses_SexLookup1`
FOREIGN KEY (`horse_sex`)
REFERENCES `TRC`.`lookup_sex` (`sex`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

USE `TRC`;
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `TRC`.`view_horse` AS SELECT 
registered_name AS 'Registered Name',
stable_name AS 'Stable Name', 
horse_birth_year AS 'Age', 
horse_height AS 'Height',
arrival_weight AS 'Weight on Arrival',
horse_sex AS 'Sex',
horse_location AS 'Location', 
arrival_date AS 'Date of Arrival',
passport_no AS 'Passport no.',
microchip_no AS 'Microchip no.',
is_deceased AS 'Alive?'
FROM `horse`;
```

If I insert into the view without specifying the columns it actually completes ok. But not when I give the columns as specified in the view.

Comment: Can you post up a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You're not trying to INSERT into the actual VIEW are you? Insert into the TABLE, and SELECT from the VIEW.

Edit. Forget it; thanks for the correction Strawberry.

Comment: You can insert into the view. That's fine - (well, with lots of caveats!) ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry I understand you can but why would you want to?

Comment: For example, you need a view if you're trying to access the table from an Oracle DB link (and your client thus is the Oracle DB). Since Oracle has a limit of 30 characters for all identifiers, it cannot handle column names longer than 30 characters. This can be solved by a view with shortened column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that illustrates inserting into the view: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280aa6/1/0